# Procedure to insert node in a nested set model with MySQL database

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-update, sql-insert, nested-sets

I'm trying to implement procedures to insert and delete nodes accordingly with http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ explanations.

For instance here's one of the 4 procedures I'm creating :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
PROCEDURE `firstChildInsert`(IN `@ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED, IN `@L` BIGINT UNSIGNED)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    UPDATE `nodes` SET `r`=`r`+2 WHERE `r`>`@L` ORDER BY `l` DESC;
    UPDATE `nodes` SET `l`=`l`+2 WHERE `l`>`@L` ORDER BY `l` DESC;
    INSERT INTO `nodes`(`id`,`l`,`r`) VALUES(`@ID`,`@L`+1,`@L`+2);
END
```

The idea being to `CALL firstChildInsert(#REF_OBJECT_ID,#PARENTNODE_LEFT_POSITION);` to insert a new node... *The three others being nextSiblingInsert(...), deleteNode(...) (and descendants), shiftNode(...)(whilst keeping descendants).*

However even changing the `ORDER BY` column to the `l` (LEFT) on when updating the `r` (RIGHT) position of all nodes at the right of the insertion point. I get the message "**Duplicate entry '#' for key 'l'**".

My `PRIMARY KEY` being done with the `l` column because I may use the same "category" in several nodes.

Therefore it's obvious I could use as a key `id` AND `l` columns but :

- What impact would it have on performances ?
- Why isn't my `ORDER BY` clause working inside the `UPDATE` statement of the `PROCEDURE` ?
- Would you consider as I did the `PROCEDURE` to be `DETERMINISTIC` ?